# How to disable automatic root login in Ubuntu 19 at startup?

Tags: login, auto-login

I have enabled automatic root login in Ubuntu 19. But I want to disable this feature.

[I have tried a lot using this link](https://vitux.com/how-to-enable-disable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/). But I cant disable this automatic root login.

I have [tried this link.](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/arch-29/cancel-automatic-login-in-systemd-4175590690/)  I have run the following command but still does not get any clue how to do this ?

```
sudo systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
```

Please help me to disable automatic root login in ubuntu 19 where I have used GDM3 ?

### Update:

I have checked my ubuntu version using lsb_release -a command. this gives me following output:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco

Comment: What OS/release are you using?   There is no Ubuntu 19, nor a Ubuntu Core 19 (or other release that uses *year* format instead of *year.month*).  Ubuntu desktop also does not have root user by default.

Comment: I have enabled root user by command.Also my ubuntu version is 19.04

Comment: The root account is disabled by default in all desktop flavors of Ubuntu, so you must have done much more than simply enable automatic login. I'm not sure how you accomplished the feat of combining enabled root and automatic login...so I'm not sure how to tell you to undo it.